# Python program returning none

Tags: python, return

The following code (allegedly) returns none.

```
def addTwo(startingvalue):
    endingvalue = startingvalue + 2 
    return endingvalue

sum1 = addTwo(5)
sum2 = addTwo(52)
print('The results of adding are ', sum1, sum2)
```

Comment: Is that typo on `addtwo`?

Comment: The only thing wrong is the lowercase `t` in `sum2 = addtwo(52)`. Aside from this, the functions do return the proper value, which are printed properly as well. What is your issue?

Comment: Oops sorry for the typo still after correction output is None here's a screenshot (https://postimg.org/image/x84h94xtj/) Thanks.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. Calls are made _inside_ function.

Answer (score 2):

As people have mentioned in the comments, you had a small typo in one of your function calls which would throw a NameError. But other than that, it works perfectly fine with the following output:

```
The results of adding are  7 54
```

Okay, here's the problem, the code in the question is properly indented, the code in [your screenshot](https://postimg.cc/image/x84h94xtj/) is improperly indented. In the screenshot lines 6,7 and 8 are indented, which means they're *inside* the function. Since the function returns on line 3 and is never called, you aren't getting the proper output.

Comment: Didn't know indentation is so crucial in python Thanks !!

Comment: Indeed! A lot of languages use special syntax like {} to define chunks of code, whereas Python pretty much always uses indentation :)